# ¿How do I solve the error git push -u origin master in the GIT console?

Tags: git, github, console, git-push

I was a mistake with the comand of GIT git push -u origin master to connect it to my remote Github repository with the local repository. ¿It may have to do with personal access token or is it something else?

That's is the error in the console of GIT:

[image: error git push -u origin master in the console of GIT]

Thanks for your help!!
By!

I hope someone can send me an image or description with the steps to solve it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem once. I solved it by using ssh key GitHub authorisation

[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)